# dynamic gridview column autocalculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview, with textboxes in templatefields, where i dynamically add columns to it.

```
 protected void grid()
 {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SerialNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Material", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Bags", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GrossWt", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TareWt", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NetWt", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BillWt", typeof(string)));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr["SerialNumber"] = 1;

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();                      
}
```

I need to have the NetWt column to have autocalulated values using the GrossWt and TareWt columns. The formula should be (grosswt-tarewt)/1000. But i dont know how to go about it. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[5] = (e.Row.Cells[3].Text - e.Row.Cells[4].Text)/1000
    }
}
```

Try this

Comment: i thought about this...but wont this take null values from the textbox initially?? and how will it display the calculated values without a postback?

Comment: it calculates them on row data bound, it is working. try it.... It will be triggered after the row has been bound, so it doesn't have null values. It won't need a postback!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user edits the values, you can add your own handler to the CellValidated event and then do whatever you like with the values:

```
    myDataGridView.CellValidated += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(myDataGridView_CellValidated);

    [...]
    private void myGridView_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == myGridView.Columns["GrossWt"].Index){
            myGridView.Rows[e.Index].Cells["NewWT"].Value = (
                myGridView.Rows[e.Index].Cells["GrossWT"].Value -
                myGridView.Rows[e.Index].Cells["TareWT"].Value ) /1000;
        }
     }
```

Comment: hey adrian...i am not able to convert my cell values to int, there is an error with the above code

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure the values in your cells are convertable to integers? When you create the cells of the gridview you should assign them the correct format so that only integers can be entered. (CellValidated only gets called when the value was valid)